# Ellipsoid mesh generation in CGAL

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I need to generate a great number of ellipsoidal meshes in CGAL. The shape of the ellipsoids is the same, they differ in position and orientation. I am looking for an efficient method so I think I have to:

- generate only one spherical mesh using CGAL::make_surface_mesh and apply a scaling transformation to it to make it an ellipsoid,
- rotate and translate the first ellipsoidal mesh to create the other meshes.

I have generated the spherical mesh following: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html.

Using:

```
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::Vector_3 Vector3;
typedef CGAL::Aff_transformation_3<K> Trans3;
```

I have written the affine transformations that scale, translate and rotate a geometric object using CGAL::Aff_transformation_3. For example, the scaling transformation is:

```
K::RT M[9]={2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};        
Trans3 sca(M[0], M[1],M[2],M[3],M[4],M[5],M[6],M[7],M[8]);
```

I can't find a way to apply those transformation on the spherical surface mesh generated from implicit function.

Do I have to generate the surface mesh using another library different from 3D Surface Mesh Generation?

What is a good package for this purpose?

I don't think it is very efficient to generate every mesh using CGAL::make_surface_mesh, is it right?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you directly mesh the ellipsoid?

Comment: Or you can apply the inverse transformation to the point in the `operator()`

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to explain why I think I shouldn't directly mesh every ellipsoid.

Comment: @sloriot , could you explain me why I should use the inverse transformation and how can I do it? I have read that the vertices_begin() iterator is non-mutable in SurfaceMeshComplex_2InTriangulation_3
 https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/classSurfaceMeshComplex__2InTriangulation__3.htm

Comment: @Enrico Someone answered your question, could you please accept the answer or give feedback in comment?

Answer (score 0):

Mesh it directly:

```
double a=4,b=2,c=1; // the radii 

FT ellipsoid_function (Point_3 p) {
  const FT x2=(p.x()*p.x())/(a*a), y2=(p.y()*p.y())/(b*b), z2=(p.z()*p.z())/(c*c);
  return x2+y2+z2-1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to generate a great number of identical ellipsoids, so it is more efficient to rotate and translate the same mesh. I have edited the question.

Comment: You first have to export it to a Polyhedron_3 using [`CGAL::output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/namespaceCGAL.html#ab2fbf4e1a4cf30fa19304138461623e7)

Comment: And I still would suggest that you first mesh an axis aligned ellipsoid before making the affine transformation, as then your triangles are nicer.

Comment: CGAL::output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron is marked as deprecated, I have used it as `CGAL::output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron(c2t3,P);`

And the compiler gives me:

error: 'output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron' is not a member of 'CGAL'

Comment: You didn't include the header (and it  is not documented which header to include).

#include <CGAL/IO/output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron.h>

I also uploaded a complete version of a program to [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/afabri/27ee5214a1ab39979c706922eb3d9bfb)

It uses the replacement of the deprecated function, and it uses Surface_mesh instead of Polyhedron_3.